# My class is creating entries in the database and I want it to stop

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working on a project using entity framework and code first. Here are my shortened classes

```
public class BenefitsForm : IAnnualForm, IAuditable 
{
    public BenefitsUser UserInfo { get; set; }
    public CoverageLevel Medical { get; set; }
}

public class MedicalPlan : IHealthPlan
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<CoverageLevel> CoverageLevels { get; set; }
}

public class CoverageLevel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual MedicalPlan MedicalPlan { get; set; }
}
```

There are 4 coverage levels in each MedicalPlan. I already have my coverage levels and medical plans made in the database. However, when I create my BenefitsForm, it creates duplicate entries for the classes (I already have them in the database). How can I prevent it from doing this? Here is a small code snippet to show how it happens.

```
BenefitsForm form = new BenefitsForm() { UserInfo = new BenefitsUser() };
using(var repo = new CoverageLevelRepository())
{
    form.Medical = repo.Retrieve(new NumericKey(formId))); //this retrieves the coveragelevel with the id I want.
}
formRepository.Create(form); // this creates a duplicate med plan and 4 duplicate coverage levels.
formRepository.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: If you know what method is creating the duplicate entry in the database, verify it does not exist, before you create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think because you're retrieving the Medical field from a *different context* than the one you're saving in -- `repo` vs. `formRepository`; `formRepository` isn't tracking the object created by `repo`, so it assumes that it's a new object, and thus creates a duplicate entry.  For performance reasons, I don't believe Entity Framework will go and insert existence checks for you -- tracking is handled internally by the object context itself; each object is bound to a single object context.  Try using the same repository to retrieve the `MedicalPlan` and write back the new `BenefitsForm`, and you shouldn't have duplicates.

```
BenefitsForm form = new BenefitsForm() { UserInfo = new BenefitsUser() }; 
using(var repo = new Repository()) 
{ 
  form.Medical = repo.Retrieve(new NumericKey(formId))); //this retrieves the coveragelevel with the id I want. 
  repo.Create(form); // this creates a duplicate med plan and 4 duplicate coverage levels. 
  repo.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of formRepository.SaveChanges() please try with to use the SaveChanges with the SaveOptions Enum

Example:

```
ObjectContext.SaveChanges(
           System.Data.Objects.SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave
                   );
```

Please see link for more information http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395500.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that using `IList<...>` instead of `ICollection<...>` for your one-to-many association is causing it to malfunction.  Try changing that.  Other than that, it may be code within your `CoverageLevelRepository` that you did not post.  For more info on associations, see [this guide](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/17/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-6-many-valued-associations.aspx)

Comment: Would having all the classes as "Serializable" cause problems?